# How to provide different mock services to test Angular 2 component?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I have two Mock services:

```
@Injectable()
class UserRegistrationServiceMock {
    registerBasicDetails(details: UserRegistrationDetails) {
        let response: UserRegistrationResponse = new UserRegistrationResponse();
        response.success = false;
        response.userMessage = 'Test Message';                
        return Observable.of(response);
    }

    registerAdvancedDetails() {        
    }
}

@Injectable()
class UserRegistrationServiceSuccessMock {
    registerBasicDetails(details: UserRegistrationDetails) {
        let response: UserRegistrationResponse = new UserRegistrationResponse();
        response.success = true;
        response.userMessage = 'Test Message';
        return Observable.of(response);
    }

    registerAdvancedDetails() {
    }
}
```

In my Jasmine test I provide its definition in the "beforeEachProviders" and "beforeEach" methods:

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [        
 provide(UserRegistrationService, { useClass: UserRegistrationServiceMock })
]);

beforeEach(inject([UserRegistrationService], (_userRegistration))
```

Then in my actual test I can reference the user registration service to initialise the component:

```
it('should create an instance', () => {
        let component: BasicRegistrationComponent =
            new BasicRegistrationComponent(null, formBuilder, promptWindow, userInfo, translator, userRegistration);
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

The question here is how can I provide the second mock implementation of the service for my component?

Answer (score 2):

You provide the second mock class the same way you provide the first.

Include it in `beforeEachProviders()` and `beforeEach`

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [        
  provide(UserRegistrationService, { useClass: UserRegistrationServiceMock }),
  provide(UserRegistrationServiceSuccess, { useClass: UserRegistrationServiceSuccessMock })
]);

beforeEach(inject([UserRegistrationService, UserRegistrationServiceSuccess], (_userRegistration, _userSuccess))
```

As a tip I would suggest only injecting what you need for each test, not injecting all dependencies into every test. (Unless you only have one test in that file). Keep `beforeEachProviders`, but instead of using `beforeEach`, do this in your component test:

```
it("should create an instance", inject([UserRegistrationService, UserRegistrationServiceSuccess], (_userRegistration : UserRegistrationServiceMock, _userSuccess : UserRegistrationServiceSuccessMock) => {
        let component: BasicRegistrationComponent =
        new BasicRegistrationComponent(null, formBuilder, promptWindow, userInfo, translator, userRegistration);
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

Also if you are using mock services you should reference them like above:
`_userRegistration : UserRegistrationServiceMock`. Basically that inject statement means: when the test is looking for `UserRegistrationService` I am passing it `UserRegistrationServiceMock` but I'm calling it `_userRegistration`. Let me know if this does not help :)

Answer (score 2):

The best and most readable way I've found to do this is by nesting an extra set of describe statements:

```
describe('SomeComponent', () => {

   describe("Normal Registration", () => {
       beforeEachProviders(() => [        
           provide(UserRegistrationService, { useClass: UserRegistrationServiceMock })
       ]);

       beforeEach(inject([UserRegistrationService], (_userRegistration))

       it('should create an instance', () => {
          let component: BasicRegistrationComponent =
             new BasicRegistrationComponent(null, formBuilder, promptWindow, userInfo, translator, userRegistration);
           expect(component).toBeTruthy();
       });
    });

    describe("Registration Success", () => {
        beforeEachProviders(() => [        
            provide(UserRegistrationService, { useClass: UserRegistrationServiceSuccessMock })
        ]);

        beforeEach(inject([UserRegistrationService], (_userRegistration))

        it('should create an instance', () => {
           let component: BasicRegistrationComponent =
              new BasicRegistrationComponent(null, formBuilder, promptWindow, userInfo, translator, userRegistration);
            expect(component).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
});
```